# Bootstrapper Package for SQL Server 2008 Native Client and SQL Server 2008 Management Objects

Tags: sql, setup-deployment, bootstrapper

I'm using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator to make bootstrapper packages for the following redistrbutables:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects
- Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
- Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types

I have a MsiProductCheck install conditions to determine if the MSI was installed, however as soon as a newer version is released, the check is back to saying that the prerequisite is needed.

I was wondering what the correct way was to determine if these components were installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with SQL 2005 Native Client, but I got the SQL 2005 Management Object correct. However I've lost the packages I created and need to recreate them, but now for SQL 2008.

MS should create these packages for us, or at least provide a community for sharing bootstrapper packages. I guess there are thousands of developers trying to figure out how to write the same bootstrapper packages, and all are reinventing the wheel with more or less luck.